# get UNICODE character instead of HEX - cURL PHP

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8, php-curl

I am using [this](http://web3o.blogspot.co.nz/2010/10/php-imdb-scraper-for-new-imdb-template.html) **scraper** for IMDB, and the problem is that some characters are in UNICODE `&#xEF;`.
I use this **scraper** with CURL, and the answer its a string encoded in UTF8
I try to get the encode of the string with **mb_detect_encoding()** and it answer with UTF-8

```
$html = $this->geturl("${imdbUrl}combined");
mb_detect_encoding($html);
```

So  I have a string with some HEX values inside, like this for example:

```
$var = 'Sa&#xEF;d Taghmaoui'
```

So I try to get the value of $html with **utf8_decode()** but no luck, I still have some characters in HEX.

So I have a few questions:

1- What's the best solution for this? I imagine different scenarios for example a read the string and with a REGEX change all the HEX codes with the character, but I am not sure if this one its the best solution, and also I dont know how to create the REGEX for this.

2- The solution can be through cURL? I mean manage some configurations to set the encoding of cURL in UTF-8 for example?

I try with the functions **recode_string** or **iconv** or **mb_convert_encoding**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well basically my problem is that the answer from the **scraper** comes with UTF-8 encoding, but before print the text I need to work the data with this functions

```
$var = 'Sa&#xEF;d Taghmaoui'
htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode($var, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```